# sf geometry column naming differences R

Tags: r, merge, sf

I've got several shapefiles stored as geopackages and I want to merge all of them by using `rbind`. But unfortunately the geometry columns are namend differently as `geometry` or `geom` and because of that I cannot `rbind` them. I can't see any reason why R is naming them differently.
They're all pointshapes from the same research area and with the same CRS and basically with same column names (besides the geometry field for some reasons).

I've tried simply renaming the geometry column resulting in the error `attr(obj, "sf_column") does not point to a geometry column`
as well as recreating the geometry column, but then it takes the same name every time.

But I found a workaround by renaming the columns and simply making the `sf` to a `data.frame` and assigning the geometry afterwars. But it seems to me a bit hacky, so maybe do you have a more elegant way or maybe you can explain me the reasons for the different names in the first place.

My code:

```
wd <- setwd("filepath")

files <- list.files(path=wd, pattern="*.gpkg", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
points_all <- data.frame()


for (i in c(1:length(files))) {
  file <- st_read(files[i])
  names(file) <- c("Value", "Coord")
  points_all <- rbind(points_all,file)
  points_all <- data.frame(points_all)
}

points_all <- st_set_geometry(points_all, points_all$Coord)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've just written this which I think will safely rename the geometry column by changing the names element and then setting the geometry column with `st_geometry` - which will affect the `sf_column` attribute.

```
rename_geometry <- function(g, name){
    current = attr(g, "sf_column")
    names(g)[names(g)==current] = name
    st_geometry(g)=name
    g
}
```

I don't see a function that will get the geometry column name, and the attribute is mentioned in the documentation so I think that is a safe way to get the name.

Use like this:

```
example(st_read)
nc = rename_geometry(nc, "gyom")
plot(nc) # should work
names(nc) # shows "gyom"
```

I don't know if an sf method for `rbind` could be written that works by ignoring different names for the geometry columns and uses maybe the first one for the output, but it might be worth a feature request to the sf github.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much! I'll ask them if an implementation is possible.

Comment: Wow! This should be requested as new feature in `sf`

Comment: See also https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1890 for an alternative in sf >= 1.0-6

Answer (score 8):

A way of renaming the geometry variable has been implemented in `sf` as explained in [this issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1890). Thus in the previous example you just use this command:

```r
st_geometry(nc) <- "gyom"
```

Comment: Perfect solution!